# Can the same Android App be used for mobile phones, tablets and Google TV?

Tags: android, google-tv

Is it possible to develop one app that can be used on mobile phones, tablets and GoogleTV?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can. Actually, this is the intention of Google. That's why; you can easily define different layout settings for different screen size, dpi, etc...

Note: Specials APIs of Google TV and Tablet are not yet available in the SDK. Yet, the special layout settings are available since 1.5. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
AshtonBRSC, thanks for the warning.

Comment: Note that the Google TV SDK has not been released so it isn't possible yet, but will be.

Comment: The Google TV Addon is released, so now you can create apps that support phone, tablet and Google TV.

Comment: Is the Google TV AddOn release for Linux only at the moment? Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537331/are-android-apps-available-on-google-tv