# Are Android apps available on Google TV?

Tags: android, google-play, google-tv

I went through this question and wanted to know if an app that I developed for cellphones or tablets would be available to Market users with a Google TV? If yes, how can I can optimize the app for the xlarge TV screen size?

[Can the same Android App be used for mobile phones, tablets and Google TV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002857/can-the-same-android-app-be-used-for-mobile-phones-tablets-and-google-tv)

Comment: Not yet. Although the SDK is out.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't create an AVD for google TV in the eclipse IDE?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If you can post the same as an answer, I would be happy to 'accept' them for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. Although the SDK is out.

Therefore you can't create an AVD for google TV in the eclipse IDE on Windows or Mac.

You can for linux.

**As of December 2011**

*EDIT*

Sorry I work on a Mac and a PC lol.

Reading now that you can create a Google TV AVD:

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator

but only with Linux

> System Requirements
>
> Linux OS with KVM. **Windows and Mac OS X are not currently supported**. Google TV emulation on a Linux workstation without KVM is also not supported.
>
> KVM requires KVM support in the OS and Intel virtualization support in BIOS. To learn more about KVM, please read the section "Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM)".
>
> Android SDK system requirements for Google TV application development, as documented in the topic Setting Up a Development Environment.
>
> The Google TV add-on. To learn about the add-on, please read the topic Google TV Add-On.

Comment: You can create an AVD, but I believe it's limited to Linux at the moment. At least I have the target option and can launch an AVD successfully.

Comment: The Android Market has been available for the Sony Google TV devices for a month, and for the Logitech Revue for about a week. You can most certainly create an AVD for Google TV in Eclipse, if you have the Google TV SDK installed -- that has been possible for about six weeks.

Comment: Sorry yeah I read the documentation about the two platforms I work on, didn't actually think Linux would sneak it in. I was wrong! Updated answer.